# Logging messages to standard output with levels

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

Below is the code snippet from an old project. While compiling with -Wall I get below numerous warnings:

```
#ifndef LOG_NONSTD_H
#define LOG_NONSTD_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG_EMERG   0
#define LOG_ALERT   1
#define LOG_CRIT    2
#define LOG_ERR     3
#define LOG_WARNING 4
#define LOG_NOTICE  5
#define LOG_INFORM  6
#define LOG_DBG     7

#define LOG_LEVEL   7

#define STD_OUT stdout
#define STD_ERR stderr

#define log_msg(prio, stream, msg, ...) \
do{\
        char *str;\
        if ((prio == LOG_EMERG) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_EMERG)) {\
            str = "EMERG";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_ALERT) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_ALERT)) {\
            str = "ALERT";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_CRIT) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_CRIT)) {\
            str = "CRIT";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_ERR) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_ERR)) {\
            str = "ERR";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_WARNING) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_WARNING)) {\
            str = "WARN";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_NOTICE) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_NOTICE)) {\
            str = "NOTICE";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_INFORM) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_INFORM)) {\
            str = "INFO";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        else if ((prio == LOG_DBG) && (LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_DBG)) {\
            str = "DEBUG";\
            fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
    } while(0)

//log_msg(LOG_ERR, STD_ERR, "\nError in opening %s", filename);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
}
```

Usage eg 1
`log_msg(LOG_INFORM, STD_OUT, "Emergency");`

Usage eg 2
`log_msg(LOG_ALERT, "Alert", "No signal payload");`

Usage eg 3 where payload is of type `char*`
`log_msg(LOG_DBG, STD_OUT, "payload = %s", payload);`

Usage eg 4 where msgSize is of type `int`
`log_msg(LOG_DBG, STD_OUT, "msgSize = %ld", msgSize)`

Warnings:

```
log_nonstd.h:29:29: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 6 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
`|29|fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %s : "msg" \n", str, __FILE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\`
```

I fiddled with format specifiers but it says it expects int, then if I give int it says expects char*  and this goes on. What is wrong with the macro expansion?
I see it is something to do with ##**VA_ARGS** if I'm not wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't show us a [mre]. It's not the macro itself that is the problem, but how it's used. Somewhere in your code, you use it with `msg` containing an `%ld` where it should be just `%d`. Also when asking questions about build errors or warnings, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build log from your [mre]. There are often other messages anbd informational notes that would give more details.

Comment: @Gerhardh - it is there. let me post full code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - sorry question edited

Comment: Do you get any errors for the first 2 usage examples? Is `LOG_DEBUG` a typo for `LOG_DBG`? What is the exact error message for these examples? It can't be about `ld` as that format specifier is not used in these examples at all. You might look at the output of the preprocessor to get what was replaced.

Comment: `##__VA_ARGS__` isn't standard C but a gcc extension. If you compile with a standard C (or C++) compiler, it will end up confused - you'll have to compile this code in a non-conforming gcc mode. How did you compile it?

Comment: @Gerhardh - Yes it is a typo. Corrected now to LOG_DBG. I understood what you said and looked into multiple places where this log_msg() was called & I was able to clear out few warnings. It is the specifiers that are causing the warnings.

Comment: @Lundin - this is a yocto compilation (custom arm gcc toolchain). Compilation string is very long. But I tried executing the code outside yocto. Now I have some clarity what is happening. If you see Usage eg: 2, the second argument expects a ```FILE*``` but ```char*``` was passed which throws warnings wherever it was used. I casted it like ```(FILE*)"Alert"``` warning is GONE but it prints nothing. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Usage eg 2 does not cause any problem in custom arm gcc toolchain (gcc version 10.3.0), it compiles and prints too but the regular gcc compiler (version 9.4.0) in Ubuntu has segmentation fault.

Comment: You can't really expect it to work if you pass a string literal where a `FILE*` is expected, do you? Why do you pass `"ALERT"` at all? It is already assigned to `str` in your macro.

Comment: You are right. Dumb move from the actual developer. And so dumb of me to not actually notice it. I understood my mistake of not noticing details. Thanks! All warnings shoo'ed away. Can you (try to) write an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Pleas, oh please, create a proper [mre]. We need to see some code that actually replicates the problem you have. Code that actually causes the errors you ask about. Then copy-paste the ***full and complete*** build-log from that example. I'm sorry, but you can't expect proper answers unless you write a proper question.

Comment: Looks like you down voted my question. I will add more details to it. But please read my last comment. The problem was solved. It was my mistake to not pay proper attention to the "usage" of the log_msg().

Comment: And since @Gerhardh did not respond to my request I will write myself what's wrong.

Comment: Quite honestly, if you have "...`msgSize` is of type `int`", why are you using `%ld` instead of `%d`?

Comment: Honestly, you need to read my previous comments. I accepted that I was dumb to not notice that. I was focusing on the log_msg macro expansion rather than how it was used in other files. Also, this is not my code and actual programmer was not interested to rectify these. I don't like warnings hence I was trying to get rid of them.  My user name has Pro in it but I'm not a Pro in programming.

Comment: What compiler are you using? If you use e.g. GCC then there will be extra notes that show where the macro is used with the invalid format specifier. While it's often best to go though error and warning messages one by one, from top to bottom, there are often notes attached to each message that needs to be read. If you build in an IDE those notes might be hidden, and you need to look in the full build log output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's basically a yocto build system 'bitbake'. Warnings were proper my understanding was not good. ChatGPT tried to help me as well but I was impatient to understand the underlying message. So, here I am taking downvotes for my impatience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is perfectly working. Problem was with usage of log_msg().
Usage eg 1 & 3 have proper usage hence no warnings there.
Usage eg 2 has argument of type char* ("Alert") where it actually expects FILE* (STD_OUT). Hence a warning there.
`log_msg(LOG_ALERT, STD_OUT, "No signal payload"); // fixes the warning`
Usage eg 4 has argument of type int where it actually expects long int. Hence a warning there.
`log_msg(LOG_DBG, STD_OUT, "msgSize = %d", msgSize) // fixes the warning`